# Need to measure how much is the data concentrated or scattered

Tags: algorithms, matlab

OK. So I have this problem: I have an array of x values corresponding to an array of your values. I want to know when is that data scattered all around and when it's quite concentrated.  As can be seen in the picture I attached: the first set of data is really scattered. The second one is pretty concentrated and the last one is concentrated the most. Thanks!! ( I'll try to post the picture in the comment since it wouldn't let me)

Comment: you forgot to attach the pictures. any reason why you are not using variance?

Comment: As mentioned above, typically the _variance_ of the data is used.  To compute this, if your data is some set $X$, then you want to compute $\sum_{x\in X} (x-E[X])^2$ where $E[X]$ is the mean of your data.  It's very likely matlab has a built in variance calculator, I'm not familiar with it though.

Comment: http://imgur.com/d9scrWo

Comment: The problem using this can be seen in the pictures. Also this is two dimensional data and the variance is one dimensional

Comment: Then find the centre of the data (sample average of coordinates for instance) and compute the total Euclidean distance (or some other metric) of all the data points from the centre (or average distance). I am typing this on my phone so I haven't thought it thru but I think it reduces to ordinary sample variance if your data is one dimensional.

Comment: I tried it, it had problems and sometimes favored the second plot and not the third plot (in my picture)